# Yii db command and CDbCriteria

Tags: yii

I have two tables `Products(id, name)` and `Views(id,count,time)`, and those two tables are not related to each other. This is my code:

```
$dbCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
SELECT P.`id`, P.`name`, V.`time` 
FROM `products` P, `views` V 
WHERE P.`type` = 2 
ORDER BY V.`time` DESC
");
$data = $dbCommand->queryAll();
```

It is working, but I want to convert this query to CDbCriteria syntax.

```
$cdb = new CDbCriteria();
$cdb->select = //???
$cdb->where = //???
$cdb->order = //???
```

How can I do this? Can somebody help me?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible, since, each criteria belongs to an active record model. So if you have two tables, so you would have two models. The only way to do this(In my opinion) would be adding a relation to a model.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use CDbCriteria, Try using query builder.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('P.id, P.name, V.time')
->from('products P, views V')
->where('P.type = :type')
->order('V.time DESC')
->queryAll(array(
    ':type' => 2
));
```